# Table doesn't exists error when adding a foreign key to existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am adding a foreign key to an column in table in a mySQL DB:

```
 ALTER TABLE Orders ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectNumber FOREIGN KEY (porj) REFERENCES proj(projno);
```

The table with the existing column is emp, the column in emp is porj, and the foreign key resides in the table proj, column projno. However I am getting the follwing error:

```
1146 - Table 'empdept.orders' doesn't exist
```

I don't understand the reference to empdept.orders, empdept is not a table, nor is 'orders' a column on any existing table within the DB, so why is it been mentioned?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The error references a qualified table name, that is your schema name is `emptdept` and the table name is `Orders`.

I can reproduce this error on MySQL 8.0 if the table `Orders` is MyISAM (or anything other than InnoDB, I assume).

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `proj` (
    ->   `projno` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`projno`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
mysql> CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    ->   `porj` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

mysql> ALTER TABLE Orders ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ProjectNumber FOREIGN KEY (porj) REFERENCES proj(projno);
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.Orders' doesn't exist
```

MyISAM tables don't support foreign key constraints.

It's a pity that the error message is so unclear. The table exists, but it doesn't exist in the InnoDB data dictionary. I guess that's their reasoning.

I don't see the same error in MySQL 5.7, I get this result instead:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

When you try to create a foreign key on a MyISAM table in MySQL 5.7, the operation is silently ignored. It doesn't cause any error, it just doesn't do it.

With the new implementation of the InnoDB data dictionary in MySQL 8.0, they finally throw an error instead of silently accepting the ALTER TABLE for the unsupported feature.

By the way, I recommend you do not use MyISAM tables anymore. They are gradually being made obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to set the primary key in the referenced table, now resolved:

```
create table proj (projno numeric(3,0) not null, pname char(5), budget numeric (7,2, PRIMARY KEY (projno)))
```